# What is the most efficient way to recursively traverse an array with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a 2d array where I'm trying to find the longest sequence path with some caveats. I have gone through and created an array that outlines all the possible paths for a given point:

```
[
  {
    "value": 8,
    "row": 0,
    "col": 0,
    "paths": [{ "row": 1, "col": 0 }, { "row": 0, "col": 1 }]
  },
  {
    "value": 2,
    "row": 0,
    "col": 1,
    "paths": [{ "row": 1, "col": 1 }, { "row": 0, "col": 0 }]
  },
  { "value": 4, "row": 0, "col": 2, "paths": [] },
  {
    "value": 0,
    "row": 1,
    "col": 0,
    "paths": [
      { "row": 0, "col": 0 },
      { "row": 2, "col": 1 },
      { "row": 1, "col": 1 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "col": 1,
    "paths": [{ "row": 0, "col": 1 }, { "row": 1, "col": 2 }]
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "col": 2,
    "paths": [
      { "row": 2, "col": 2 },
      { "row": 2, "col": 1 },
      { "row": 1, "col": 1 }
    ]
  },
  { "value": 3, "row": 2, "col": 0, "paths": [{ "row": 2, "col": 1 }] },
  {
    "value": 7,
    "row": 2,
    "col": 1,
    "paths": [{ "row": 1, "col": 2 }, { "row": 2, "col": 0 }]
  },
  { "value": 9, "row": 2, "col": 2, "paths": [{ "row": 1, "col": 2 }] }
]
```

So for the first point `8 -> (0,0)` it can can go to `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` and once in those points, that point might have 0 to n paths to follow. I have to be able to test every possible path to calculate the longest chain.

I can get it to calculate a single path but I'm pretty stuck in testing every possible outcome.

Comment: please add what you have done already and where it fails.

Comment: it doesn't fail. I've taken the input which is a 2d array `[[8,2,4],[0,6,1],[379]]` and calculated all the possible paths for every point based on some specific logic. My code follows a single path for a given point (essentially follow the first item of the subsequent path array). I just cant figure out how I would go about testing every possible path in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an object with only arrays of next items and map the items with an upcoming [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for the nested nodes. To prevent circular result, you need to check in advane and return only the pathes up to an already visited node.

For a result, you need to filter the longest chain. This result gets all chains and uses a compact join with a separator.

```js
const
    go = path => k => path.includes(k.toString())
        ? path.join('-')
        : object[k].flatMap(go(path.concat(k.toString()))),
    getKey = ({ row, col }) => [row, col].join('|');

var data = [{ value: 8, row: 0, col: 0, paths: [{ row: 1, col: 0 }, { row: 0, col: 1 }] }, { value: 2, row: 0, col: 1, paths: [{ row: 1, col: 1 }, { row: 0, col: 0 }] }, { value: 4, row: 0, col: 2, paths: [] }, { value: 0, row: 1, col: 0, paths: [{ row: 0, col: 0 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 1 }] }, { value: 6, row: 1, col: 1, paths: [{ row: 0, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 2 }] }, { value: 1, row: 1, col: 2, paths: [{ row: 2, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 1 }] }, { value: 3, row: 2, col: 0, paths: [{ row: 2, col: 1 }] }, { value: 7, row: 2, col: 1, paths: [{ row: 1, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 0 }] }, { value: 9, row: 2, col: 2, paths: [{ row: 1, col: 2 }] }],
    keys = Object.assign(...data.map(o => ({ [getKey(o)]: o.value }))),
    object = Object.assign(...data.map(o => ({ [keys[getKey(o)]]: o.paths.map(o => keys[getKey(o)]) }))),
    result = Object.keys(object).map(go([]));

console.log(result);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```